# Mongos throttling query speed

Tags: java, mongodb

I've got a mongo v2.6.4 cluster with:

- 2 app servers running mongos instances
- 3 standalone config servers
- 3 mongod servers in a replica set

From the app servers I can connect to the cluster with no problem. However, each server is limited to about 1k queries per second (this figure from a quick findOne on a small collection using the Java driver). In my dev environment on a small vm I am seeing over 4k queries per second with the same test app.

What is really strange is if I add more app servers I can get about 1k queries per second from each app server concurrently (i.e. 4 app servers can get about 4k queries per second total). This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the mongos setting which is throttling the query performance.

Am I crazy? Is there any way to boost performance from mongos?

---

**Edit 1 (adding sample code and details about mongos config)**

The mongos config is 100% default except

```
configdb=server1,server2,server3
maxConns=10000
```

Code for the quick test running on one of the app servers

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

class Tester {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("192.168.1.100");

            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("my_db");

            db.authenticate("my_user", "my_passwd".toCharArray());

            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("my_collection");

            long counter = 10000l;

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
                coll.findOne();
            }

            double totalTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0;

            System.out.println(counter + " counter find operations in " + totalTime + " seconds (" + (counter/totalTime) + " per second)");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us some code. What is your write concern? What are the settings of your mongos instances?

Comment: I'm just using the default read preference which is primary.

Comment: Your test app uses a single thread with synchronous queries; use multiple threads or asynchronous queries if you want higher query throughput from your test app.

Comment: The test app gets 4k qps in a small dev environment and only 1k in a big production environment. I really don't think the test app is the problem here.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that if the dev environment is all on a single machine and the production environment is distributed, the dev system would likely be faster.

Comment: I suppose it could be, but the machines are all on the same network. The mongo cluster itself is handling the traffic without any issue at all. I can add more mongos servers and push more traffic that way but my app servers are totally underutilized because they can't push enough traffic to the mongo cluster.

Comment: I moved everything into a single replica set and hit that directly (bypassing the mongos completely) and got only slightly better performance. I guess the network latency is just an absolute killer for mongo perf.

Comment: Ok, first of all @JohnnyHK is right about what he said about threading. Although the MongoDB driver uses a connection pool, you are using a single thread. About the performance issue: you are using an undetermined query, not holding the shard key. Please modify your code so that it holds the shard key. What I assume is that the mongos needs a long time to select the random document for each query, it may even be that it updates the metadata from the config servers for each query - I couldn't explain a 1 to 4 ratio otherwise. Let us know your findings.

Comment: Also, please let us know the RAM of the servers. With 1000 connections, we may run into a memory problem on the cluster.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg you did see that I put everything into a single replica set and didn't see any perf improvement right? To me that says it has absolutely nothing to do with the shard key. The replica servers have 30GB of RAM and run nothing but mongo. MMS tells me that non-mapped virtual memory is under 1GB and number of connections is constant at 150 with my actual app running which is multithreaded.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that my mongos instances are each showing hundreds of connections while the primary mongod is only showing 150. I'm not sure how to explain that discrepancy.

Comment: @jcdnk111: Regradless of what your shard key is or the size of your cluster, the metadata is checked. So please try as advised. It may well be a bug which we could investigate. My assumption is that instead of using the metadata cache, the config servers are checked for nondeterministic queries. If you refuse to verify theories, we can rather roll dice to find out what it could be. mongos have a connection pool of their own. So even when 1000 clients are connected to mongos, it may just have 150 connections to the shards.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm not refusing. I'll give it a go just to see what happens but I think you're still missing the part where I bypassed mongos altogether.

Comment: Well, I am not. With sharding: slow. Without sharding: faster. Conclusion: sharding has a configuration problem. We need to test that out. You did not mention that you bypassed the production cluster's mongo_s_ (how do you access the sharded collection then?). In case you do so and get the same results as for the sharded version, this has to be further investigated. But you question was about mongos.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg quoting myself from two days ago on this very post "I moved everything into a single replica set and hit that directly (bypassing the mongos completely) and got only slightly better performance. I guess the network latency is just an absolute killer for mongo perf."

Comment: Ok, what does that tell us? To broad of a question. This has nothing to do with the original question any more. Here is my suggestion: check your write concern and the network latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information here, I think the most likely explanation is the following: your test code is single threaded. When you test with single threaded code, you are measuring the latency of operations, not the throughput, because MongoDB can do many operations simultaneously (measuring only latency in the sense that the limiting factor/slow step is latency of a single operation, so the throughput number is not the best that can be expected). The throughput numbers are not indicative of the real throughput limitations of MongoDB in this setup. This holds for all of your setups since it's the same test code. Your different numbers for the sharded, replica, and local tests just mean you had different latencies for those setups. Latency order sharded > replica > local makes sense, given the config server checks that occur in sharded setups.

Comment: It is very clear now that the network latency is the problem here. Even relatively small latency causes a pretty significant performance drag.